# AJAX requests in ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, iis, asp.net-core

I need to make requests back to my server in my web app, for example, the user clicks a table item and it loads extra data in another part of the same page.

So far I have been doing this via AJAX requests, which have been working fine (although if this is not the best practice way I would welcome any alternative suggestions).

The problem I found is that the requests no longer worked when I published the site to IIS. Looking into it I have found that the URL is missing something when called from IIS.

For example, in debug (localhost), I make my request like this:

```
await $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'products?handler=productid=' + productId});
```

...where 'products' is the name of the page I made the request from, for which the path is `localhost/products`.

When being hosted from IIS the url is now `localhost/mynewapp/products`, and so the base path has changed, which is why my requests don't work in IIS.

I've fixed this by adding the following JS method:

```
function GetBaseUrl() {
    var url = window.location;

    return url.pathname;
}
```

… and then changing the AJAX call to:

```
await $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: GetBaseUrl() + '?handler=productid=' + productId});
```

This works in both debug and IIS.

This just feels a bit hack-y to me, and so my question is, what is the proper way to deal with this situation?

Comment: this looks like a configuration issue with iis. you should be able to host your site directly at `localhost` instead of `localhost/mynewapp`. information on the bindings you have set up for your sites in iis may be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I could not use the default port on localhost because I am also running an Apache web server there for another web app, and it is using the default port 80. I am replacing that app with the new ASP version but I have to run both until the new one is ready.

Comment: I believe you can edit the bindings for the iis site in such a way that one is run at `localhost` and one is run at something like `mynewapp`. Its possible to have 2 sites running on port 80. You just can't have bindings for both that are *:80